# 'kubectl run' redis-cli directly

Tags: redis, kubectl, redis-cli

I want to start a container and directly run `redis-cli` interactively inside. For some reason, in my attempts, the input is always ignored.

Launching an interactive shell and then launching the program manually works:

```
# in my local shell:
$ kubectl run redis-cli --image redis:latest --attach --leave-stdin-open --rm -it --command -- bash
# then in container shell:
root@redis-cli:/data# redis-cli -h redis.example.com
# now the redis-cli shell is open:
redis.example.com:6379>
```

How do I combine this into one command that brings me directly into the `redis-cli` shell? I've tried the following, but I see no prompt and all my input is ignored. I can't even ctrl-C or ctrl-D out of it.

```sh
kubectl run redis-cli2 --image redis:latest --attach --leave-stdin-open --rm -it --command -- redis-cli -h redis.example.com --stat
# or
kubectl run redis-cli2 --image redis:latest --attach --leave-stdin-open --rm -it --command -- bash -ic -- "redis-cli -h redis.example.com --stat"
```

If I do a `--stat`, I see command output. If I do a `ping`, I see the ping arrive at the Redis server (using `monitor` from another container) but I never see any output and the pod goes into `CrashLoopBackOff` before terminating.

At this point, I'm not sure if this behavior is specific to `redis-cli` or the `redis` image or if this behavior is the same for other interactive programs (well, at least `bash` seems to work as expected).

Comment: What image/deployment is used for redis itself? To have minimal reproducible example.

Comment: In my case, it's an AWS ElastiCache instance, but I don't expect it to matter. Running the Redis server in the same k8s cluster is probably easier way to reproduce the situation.

Comment: Well, I saw what you said, I tried adding verbosity level to max with `--v=9`, pod is scheduled and waits for something else. Moreover if you press like 31 times on any keys, it will show you the prompt. Same happens to another image with `redis-cli`. Not sure why.

Comment: By the way what version of `kubectl` and cluster is used? It may have different behaviour

Answer (score 7):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand

---

I found a workaround, most likely this is related to `redis-cli` container and its implementation. The same behaviour is observed with different image of `redis-cli` - `docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.5-debian-10-r34`

When the command from question is run, after pod is created `redis-cli`, this message is shown:

```
$ kubectl run redis-cli3 --image redis:latest --attach --leave-stdin-open --env REDIS_PASSWORD=$REDIS_PASSWORD --rm -it -- redis-cli -h redis-master -a $REDIS_PASSWORD
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
```

It should get `enter` as a key, but it doesn't work.

Surprisingly `shift + r` combination is accepted and shows `redis-cli` connected.

Comment: Can confirm, `shift + r` brings up the prompt. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @BalzGuenat Unfortunately I don't know, this is the reason why I made this workaround as community wiki in hope that someone can actually add this to my answer or add their one. However I think this should be addressed to `redis-cli` app developers so they can trace what where and why.

Comment: I would like to know this too. I see similar things with the output not displaying for containers like busybox when attempting to use telnet (but strangely the output shows up in `kubectl logs`..). `shift + r` trick unfortunately doesn't work for busybox like it does with the redis container..

Comment: Really curious about how/why `shift + r` works. There's no way I would have figured this out - thanks for sharing the solution!